# Google App Engine, Datastore object woes

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, for-loop, google-cloud-datastore

So I'm not sure why, but my program can't seem to discern whether `r` is in results

I wonder as to whether or not this has anything to do with Cloud Datastore objects

```
terms = query.split()
res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Assignment ORDER BY created DESC")
results = []
for term in terms:
    term.strip()
    for r in res:
        #WHY THE CRAP DOESNT THIS WORK....
        #if r is in results... it still appends r to results
        if term in r.name and r not in results:
            results.append(r)
        if r.tags:
            if term in r.tags and r not in results:
                results.append(r)
```

Comment: What do you mean that r is in results already? It can't possibly be, because you are iterating over a list of distinct Assignment objects. Do you perhaps mean that r.name is in results?

Comment: It adds r to results even when r is already in results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
for r in res:
```

is inside the loop

```
for term in terms:
```

res is a query.  So when you call

```
for r in res:
```

it's really calling

```
for r in res.run():
```

So the code is executing the query and getting a new set of results *every time* through the outer loop.  So these new result objects do not match the result objects you may have saved in a previous iteration of the outer loop.

You could change "results = []" to be a dictionary instead and use the keys of the entities as keys in the dictionary and then the comparison check would work.  However, it's very inefficient to be executing this query many times inside the outer loop.

It looks like the goal of your code is to find out which Assignment entities contain the search terms in either the Assignment.name or Assignment.tags properties.  If this is the case then I would suggest swapping things around and doing something like the following:

```
terms = query.split()
assignments = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Assignment ORDER BY created DESC")
assignmentsWithTerms = []

for assignment in assignments:
    for term in terms:
        if term in assignment.name or (assignment.tags and term in assignment.tags):
            assignmentsWithTerms.append(assignment)
            continue
```

This approach will only execute the GqlQuery once so it will be much faster and cheaper. Also, as you loop through the results, it adds the assignment to the list as soon as the first term is found and then moves on, again making it faster.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!  I have one more question though: how many reads does this take?  Say I have 1000 assignments.  I'm worried this will cost me massively.

Comment: Well if you have 1,000 assignments then it will be 1,000 read calls + 1 read for the query itself.  So 1,001 reads total. App Engine pricing is SUPER cheap. 100,000 reads will cost you 6 cents, so your loop here would be 6/100th of a penny. More details on pricing here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing#cost_resource

For comparison, with your original approach, it would have used 1,001 reads x the number of terms.

Comment: Wow thanks again.  Say there are 1 million assignments.  I would then be spending 10 cents every time someone searches the database.  How do  places like google with trillions of things to index and search through every time someone searches not go bankrupt? And more importantly, how do I make my searching more cost efficient?  (Just ideas and theories help)

Comment: Yes, this code can be expensive if your goal is to just provide a search mechanism for users.  If you had millions of entities you would probably want to tokenize Assignment.name and Assignment.tags.  App Engine actually has a Search API to handle full-text searching which is what I would recommend if you're looking to implement search at scale.  If you are just getting started with App Engine then it may be a lot to take on at first, but the docs are fairly comprehensive: [GAE Python Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/)